# How to omit term frequency in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

In Apache Solr there is an `omitTermFreqAndPositions` property, and there is an `omitPositions` property. Is there a built in way to omit term frequency but preserve term positions when a field's score is calculated, or is it otherwise simple to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless you use a custom similarity class. These are field specific from Solr 4.x, so you can have a custom similarity for one field if you don't want term frequency to contribute to the score by returning 1.0f for the termfreq regardless of how many times the term occurs in the field.