# solr config changes omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"

Tags: solr

i'm using solr version 6.3 when i set omitTermFreqAndPositions="true", i'm getting the following error "msg":"field \"product_name\" was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery (phrase=product_name:\"basmati rice\")", It works fine for single word. Please help

Answer (score 4):

You're asking for a query that requires positions to be present (i.e. a phrase query) - a phrase needs to know the position of the tokens to decide if they're after / close to each other).

When you're asking Solr to drop the position information, you're telling it "don't store position information, I'm not going to use that anyway". Then you're trying to use it, and Solr says "You can't do that, you asked me to not store that information".

You'll have to drop `omitTermFreqAndPositions` and reindex your content for phrase searching to work (and any other feature that require position information).

Comment: thanks a lot for clarification but my problem is yet not resolved, my previous question " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972082/solr-exact-search-ignore-duplicate-phrase " that you replied to set omitTermFreqAndPositions =true please have look at previous question.

Comment: As I said in the previous answer, that answer is valid _if you do not depend on or use positions_. It seems you need positions, and thus, if you want to avoid the score for term frequency, you'll probably [have to create a custom similarity class that ignores termfreqs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819056/how-to-omit-term-frequency-in-apache-solr).

Comment: thanks sir for your valuable suggestion. could you please suggest as where to add this class i have never changed in any file except schema.xml.
public class CustomSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

        //multiple occurrences of terms doesn't affect its relevancy
        @Override
        public float tf(float freq) {
                return 1;
        }
}